# Swift 4 - Align two columns of UILabel views

Tags: ios, swift

I got a `ViewController` with a bunch of `Labels` ordered in 2 columns (title and description values). All the `Labels` are children of the main `View`.
I want the right column with the description Labels aligned vertically:

[image]

**My first attempt:**

I set a *fixed width constraint* `width = 180` to each `Label` of the left column. Then each `Label` of the right column had a *constraint* to the corresponding `Label` to its left.
This worked and looked fine, but I got this warning I wanted to get rid of:

> Fixed width constraints may cause clipping

**My second attempt:**

Deleted all *fixed width constraints* of the left side `Labels` to get rid of the warning. Right side wasn't aligned anymore.
In `viewDidLoad()` I tried setting all left side `Labels`' *frame sizes* to the size of the longest `Label` (in my case "Some long long text")

```
    shorterTitle.frame.size = longTitle.frame.size
    tinyTitle.frame.size = longTitle.frame.size
```

This didn't have any visible impact though (left constraints of the right Labels don't seem to be dynamic).

**My third attempt:**

I ignored the different sizes of the left side `Labels` but looked at those on the right. 
I check the x position the right side `Label` of the longest left side `Label` and set this position to all other right side `Labels`:

```
    secondDes.frame.origin.x = firstDes.frame.origin.x
    thirdDes.frame.origin.x = firstDes.frame.origin.x
```

This worked out fine but there's a problem to it:

This doesn't work if the value `Labels` are empty. In my app these are empty first and then the information of the right side `Labels` gets downloaded from a webserver.

So if I do this:

```
    secondDes.frame.origin.x = firstDes.frame.origin.x
    thirdDes.frame.origin.x = firstDes.frame.origin.x

    firstDes.text = "test1"
    secondDes.text = "test2"
    thirdDes.text = "test3"
```

the right side won't be aligned correctly.

So I changed the order so the text gets set first and therefore the `Labels` get a new width size depending on their new text.

```
    firstDes.text = "test1"
    secondDes.text = "test2"
    thirdDes.text = "test3"

    secondDes.frame.origin.x = firstDes.frame.origin.x
    thirdDes.frame.origin.x = firstDes.frame.origin.x
```

Surprisingly this doesn't work neither. 
The reason is: The text attributes are set but by the time the last 2 lines are executed the sizes of the `Labels` haven't adjusted yet.
So I would have to wait a little bit for the sizes to be applied and then call the last two lines again.

If I did that the user would be able to see the text jump though.

Hope you guys have an idea.

Comment: Hi, use UIstackView and it will work like a charm :)

Comment: I am using 1st method and facing no problem... what did you meant by **Fixed width constraints may cause clipping** ??

Comment: @dahiya_boy That is a warning that pops up when you use fixed values like in my first attempt.

Comment: @Mr.Ahtazaz I tried that too before all the above. One horizontal stackview containing to vertical stack views. Problem was that I couldn't tell the left one to take lets say 30% percent of the screen and the right one 70%.

Comment: `UIStackView ` solve your problem

Comment: @RolfWolf Add your constraint for 1st attemp

Comment: you should show us the constraints from the first attempt. the warning just hints that the values you selected could lead to text being clipped o smaller device. That should be easily fixable.

Comment: I vote to close as essential code — the constraints — is missing.

Comment: @dahiya_boy This is my first xCode project so I don't know how to retrieve the source code of all my constraints

Comment: Consider using 3 horizontal stackviews (each with 2 labels) and a vertical one in which you embed the other 3. Change the distribution to fill equally and it should be working as you intended.

Comment: Use multiple stackviews and embrace a lot of code duplication. Please use collectionview for this/uitableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout should be the best approach. 
Regarding solution 1:
The UILabels firstDes, secondDes and thirdDes are looking like being horizontal centered. If you now enforce a width of 160 it will absolutely have overlapping/breaking constraints.
A iPhone 5s/LE will have a width of 320. If the "Some long long text:" label has a 180 width it will overlap the "test1" Label.

Normally its best to use an intrinsic approach. Let the control figure out how much room it need for its text.

If it is your first project I suggest you have a look on some tutorials for Autolayout. (Ray Wenderlich for instance)

Edit: 
Suggestion from comments. Use a UIView as Container. Place all UILabels there and align them as u like. The UILabels "test2"and "test3"have LayoutContraints that tells them to have the same leading as "test1". 
Image 2 shows the constraints you are looking in the StoryBoard editor. Adding them by code is less trivial if you are unfamiliar with Autolayout.

[image]
[image]

Comment: there's a constraint for spacing between left Label and right Label though. It did work on all devices, its just the warning I didn't like

Comment: Thats the reason for the warning. XCode is aware of all valid device dimensions. Have a look for yourself. In the StoryBoard editor you display everything as a concrete type of iPhone (XR I think). On the bottom of the window, click on "view as.." and select a smaller device. You will see how your labels behave then. Try to find a set of rules that dosen't conflict. If you absolutely want some spacing between left/right, then place all labels within a UIView and center the UIView in the Superview. Will look way cleaner

Comment: Just checked out your edited answer. That's exactly what I was trying to do in my third attempt programmatically. I was gonna do it with constraints first but I couldn't find a constraint like that.

Comment: For my test2 Label most constraints are disabled just like in your screenshot. 
But I could modify my existing constraint of test2 to test2.Leading Equal test1.Leading and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. Mark the question as answered, then it wont show up as unresolved.

Answer (score 1):

### How to set UI from 1st method

---

1. In your VC take `Horizontal-StackView` first and give it some constraints. Right now I am giving it

   - Leading, trailing - 10 (constant)
   - Vertically center to the Vc view.
   - height - 200 (constant) .. later we will remove this
2. First we will set first topmost view and then we will replicate same views.So now add a single view in your `stackview`. Its say its view1.
3. Add left label (`labelLeft`) in `view1` and give it constraint :

   - Leading, top, bottom - 5 (constant)
   - Width - 80 (constant) .. you can set as per your need
4. Now set middle label (`labelMid`) for colon (if you do not wanted this then skip this step) and give constraint :

   - Leading to the `labelLeft` - 5 (constant)
   - Top to the `labelLeft`
5. Now set rightLabel (`labelRight`) and give constaints :

   - Leading to the `labelMid` - 5 (constant)
   - Top to the `labelLeft`
   - Trailing - 5 (constant)
6. Now set number of lines of each label as zero (0) and remove stackView Height constraint. Set text in `labelLeft` and `labelRight` whatever length you wanted to be and see the magic below.

**Outputs :**

> First Output (Left label is longer)
>
> [image]
>
> Second Output (Right label is longer)
>
> [image]

7. For multiple views you can directly copy the `view1` and paste it in the stackView like below.

[image]

**Final Output:**

> [image]
>
> Background purple colour is the main view.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is static then you should use UIStackView. And if your data is dynamic then UICollectionView is better option. In that case you can create a single prototype cell containing your label and then use dequeueReusableCell to use that cell. I hope you get some idea if you have understanding of UICollectionView.